# Google Maps API: Customize Text for Scroll Wheel Zooming

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I change the message which one gets when trying to zoom into the map:

> Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map

I would like to change the wording of this message. The Maps API doesn't offer a way to change it.

The only solution which comes to my mind is using jQuery to replace the text after the map initialization - but for some reason this does not work:

```
// Replace Zoom-In message:
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', () => {
    $('p.gm-style-pbt').text("Zum Zoomen der Karte CTRL + Maus-Scrollrad benutzen");
});
```

It seems that Maps API inserts the message after loading the tiles.

---

After some more testing: A "brute force" way is changing the text on scroll events:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('p.gm-style-pbt').text("Zum Zoomen ...");
});
```

But there must be a better solution than this.

---

Edited:

**Why I want to change the text?**

- The German, French and Italian translations from Google differ a bit: In
  French, it says: "CTRL + scroll wheel". In German and Italian it's
  only "... + scroll".
- The German text from Google says: "Strg+Scrollen", but
  Swiss German keyboard's control key is labeled CTRL.
- We simply want to use our own texts and translations, which are more suitable.

Comment: *By default, the Maps JavaScript API uses the user's preferred language setting as specified in the browser, when displaying textual information such as the names for controls, copyright notices, driving directions and labels on maps.* That's in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization).

Comment: I read the docs, of course, but it does not say how this message can be changed.

Comment: Other than the map content itself, the language of this message should match the website language (which depends on the domain name and not on the user's preferences).

Comment: It will match the browser language. The website language doesn't depend on the domain name. If you need to change this behavior according to some settings of your own, then read the docs I linked, everything is explained.

Comment: How you know how my website works? It's multi domain, and it's language changes depending on the domain name. Please read the title of my question: I want to change the text, and not the language of the Google Map. There are several reasons why the default text does not meet the needs of my site. And the API does not allow to change this text - at least it's not documented.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was downvoted. No solution yet. But what I did as a temporary workaround was adding this CSS: `p.gm-style-pbt::after { content: ' (Some additional explanation)'; }'`

Comment: What you are trying to do is a hack. It's undocumented, it's bad and it might even be against their TOS. Why don't you open a bug or feature request if as you said the text seems wrong?

Comment: Yes I may open a feature request. But first I wanted to be sure if this is a new feature at all. And the website has to be ready by now.

Comment: Why is adding additional CSS bad? I really don't understand this. All I do is adding some text. I don't change copyright or other legal notes. Such comments here are criticism on what I do or not do, and no technical advices.

Comment: Don't use undocumented methods. That's an advice, not criticism. I really don't care what you do with your code. Use a CSS class. That's fine. And when Google changes the name of that class, your code will stop working. Then you can come here again and ask why it doesn't work anymore. I gave you advices and also a solution which is to open a bug in the issue tracker if you think these messages are a problem. Did you do it? Another "solution" would be to allow scroll wheel zooming so that the messages don't show. That was my last comment on this question!